# How to use .prev with a Meteor event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

Yesterady I asked how I could remove the input before my button [How to remove the input element before my button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243115/how-to-remove-the-input-element-before-my-button) and I got an answer who worked in the snippet. Now I try to use it in my event but I can't remove the field, I can only remove the button.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
'click .removeField': function(event, template){
    $(this).prev('input').remove();
    $(event.target).prev('input').remove();
    $(event.target).prev().prev('input').remove();
    $(event.target).remove();
  }
```

the `$(event.target)` is `i.fa.fa-times` so I tried with  `prev().prev('input')` to be in `a -> input`

My HTML is the following one:

```
<div class="form-style-2">
 <div class="form-style-2-heading"></div>
 <form action="" method="post">
 <label>
  <span>Container name
  <span class="required">*</span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="" required/>
 </label>
 <label id="labelEnv">
  <span>Environment
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="input-field env"/><a class="removeField" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
  <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
 </label>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases `$(event.target)` will be `<i class="fa fa-times">` and it has no previous input. Let's get up to parent `<label>` then remove children within it:

```
$(event.target).closest('label').children('input, .removeField').remove();
```

**Update** if you have several inputs and you need to remove the input just before `a`:

```
var et = $(event.target);
if (et.is('i')) et = et.parent('a');
et.prev('input').remove().end().remove();
```

Comment: I can have `n` `<input>` field that's why I need to remove the one just before the `<a><i>`

Comment: if you have several inputs within the label, the label won't work as expected. Click on label should fire focus event on the linked input.

Comment: The thing I want to do is to remove the input before my `<a class="removeField">` but I can have `n` inputs

Comment: well, see the Update above

Comment: you are a hero ! It works with the update ! Thank you so much